# Seven segment display with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, ifthenelse

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\binary}[3]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\number{int(#1*2^0+#2*2^1+#3*2^2)}
}
\newcommand{\sieben}[1]{

    \draw[gray,opacity=.3,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
    \draw[gray,opacity=.3,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
    \draw[xshift=.7cm,gray,opacity=.3,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
    \draw[xshift=.7cm,gray,opacity=.3,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
    \draw[gray,opacity=.3,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
    \draw[gray,opacity=.3,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
    \draw[gray,opacity=.3,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}{
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
    }{}

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
    }{}

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);;
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
    }{}

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{3}}{
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
    }{}

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{4}}{
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
    }{}

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{5}}{
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
    }{}

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{6}}{
            \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
    }{}

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{7}}{
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
    }{}

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{8}}{
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
    }{}

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{9}}{
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
    }{}

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{a}}{
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
    }{}

%   \ifnum#1>9
%       \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
%       \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
%       \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
%       \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
%       \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
%   \fi

}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xslant=0]
        \sieben{a}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=1.5cm]
            \binary{1}{1}{1} % seven in dual system
            \sieben{\number}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

My problem is: When I uncomment the commented part in the definition of the command (`\ifnum#1>9 …`) and I type as an argument the letter "a", I get an error. But when I comment this part, I don't.

My question is: How can I fix this error?

Comment: a is not a number, you should use something like `\sieben{1}`. If you want the argument to be a hexadecimal you should use `\ifnum"#1` and `\sieben{A}`.

Comment: How about `\ifcase#1`? Happy new year!

Comment: @marmot: This was exactly that what I was looking for. Thank you and a happy new year!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely I do not understand your question. But I'd like to argue that one should first check if the argument is a number (I only check if it is an `a` but this could be extended) and then use `\ifcase` for the integer cases.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\binary}[3]{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\number{int(#1*2^0+#2*2^1+#3*2^2)}
}
\newcommand{\sieben}[1]{
    \draw[gray,opacity=.3,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
    \draw[gray,opacity=.3,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
    \draw[xshift=.7cm,gray,opacity=.3,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
    \draw[xshift=.7cm,gray,opacity=.3,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
    \draw[gray,opacity=.3,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
    \draw[gray,opacity=.3,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
    \draw[gray,opacity=.3,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{a}}{%\typeout{a}
       \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
       \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
       \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
       \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
       \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
    }{%
      \ifcase#1
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
      \or
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
      \or
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);;
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
      \or
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
      \or
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
      \or
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
      \or
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
      \or
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
      \or
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
      \or
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,-.05) --+ (.5,0);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
      \or
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,0) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[xshift=.7cm,red,line width=3pt] (0,.6) --+ (0,.5);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,1.18) --+ (.5,0);
          \draw[red,line width=3pt] (.1,.55) --+ (.5,0);
      \or   
    \fi}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xslant=0]
        \sieben{a}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=1.5cm]
            \binary{1}{1}{1} % seven in dual system
            \sieben{\number}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I meant that when I have a number which is larger then 9 I get the "E" (for error).

Comment: @current_user I just tried ` \sieben{10}` and it worked. What did you try?

Comment: Now it works. This is funny, I promise I tried exactly this code and it didn't work. Now it works. I just looked up at my tmp folder and it was the exact same code and didn't work (also checked up the log file) …

Answer (score 9):

A PSTricks solution only for fun purposes. I am really sorry if my algorithm is not so smart, but at least I can save more keystrokes.

## Version B

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\newif\ifa\newif\ifb\newif\ifc\newif\ifd\newif\ife\newif\iff\newif\ifg
\def\seg#1{%
    \atrue\btrue\ctrue\dtrue\etrue\ftrue\gtrue
    \ifcase#1
        \gfalse%0
    \or
        \afalse\bfalse\cfalse\dfalse\gfalse%1
    \or
        \bfalse\efalse%2
    \or
        \bfalse\cfalse%3
    \or
        \afalse\cfalse\dfalse%4
    \or 
        \cfalse\ffalse%5
    \or
        \ffalse%6
    \or
        \bfalse\cfalse\dfalse\gfalse%7
    \or
        %8
    \or
        \cfalse%9
    \fi
    \begin{pspicture}[nodesep=12pt,linewidth=12pt,linecap=1,linecolor=red](3,6)
        \pnodes{s}(0,0)(3,0)(3,3)(3,6)(0,6)(0,3)
        \ifa\pcline(s3)(s4)\fi
        \ifb\pcline(s4)(s5)\fi
        \ifc\pcline(s5)(s0)\fi
        \ifd\pcline(s0)(s1)\fi
        \ife\pcline(s1)(s2)\fi
        \iff\pcline(s2)(s3)\fi
        \ifg\pcline(s2)(s5)\fi
    \end{pspicture}}
\begin{document}
\foreach\i in {0,1,...,9}{\seg{\i}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Version A

A more compact solution.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\def\o#1#2#3{\expandafter\unless\csname if#1\endcsname\pcline(s#2)(s#3)\fi}
\newif\ifa\newif\ifb\newif\ifc\newif\ifd\newif\ife\newif\iff\newif\ifg

\def\p#1{%
    \ifcase#1
        \gtrue%0
    \or
        \atrue\btrue\ctrue\dtrue\gtrue%1
    \or
        \btrue\etrue%2
    \or
        \btrue\ctrue%3
    \or
        \atrue\ctrue\dtrue%4
    \or 
        \ctrue\ftrue%5
    \or
        \ftrue%6
    \or
        \btrue\ctrue\dtrue\gtrue%7
    \or
        %8
    \or
        \ctrue%9
    \fi
    \begin{pspicture}[nodesep=12pt,linewidth=12pt,linecap=1,linecolor=red](3,6)
        \pnodes{s}(0,0)(3,0)(3,3)(3,6)(0,6)(0,3)
        \o{a}{3}{4}
        \o{b}{4}{5}
        \o{c}{5}{0}
        \o{d}{0}{1}
        \o{e}{1}{2}
        \o{f}{2}{3}
        \o{g}{2}{5}
    \end{pspicture}}
\begin{document}
\foreach\i in {0,1,...,9}{\p\i}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wonder which one saves more keystrokes: (A) letting the default value of newly created conditional macros be false and turn them true or (B or the current algorithm) in which the newly created conditional macros are set true first  and change them to false later on.

Comment: The ifthen tricks are very elegant. +1

Comment: This is for me the simplest solution. +1!

Answer (score 6):

Not a Ti*k*Z answer, but... a couple of years ago I wrote (mostly for fun) a small package `sevseg` to draw seven-segment figures (and a couple of other symbols) with `pict2e`. The package is not on CTAN but can be [downloaded from GitHub](https://github.com/dcampagnari/sevseg). The repository contains also a short documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sevseg}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
See \sevseg{123}, or \sevseg[bg=black,on=red,off=darkgray,scale=4]{17:59}
\end{document}
```

[image]

All figures from 0 to 9 as well as the letters A to F are supported (uppercase or lowercase doesn't matter, the output is the same), together with minus sign, colon, period (and comma, which also outputs a period):

[image]

Unsupported characters throw a warning.

Comment: *The package is not on CTAN*. Why??

Comment: @Sigur Because I don't think it's written well enough to be on CTAN. (And I have no idea how to use `dtx` files...)

Comment: @Sigur Let's put it like this: The package is not *yet* on CTAN. Maybe one day, when I'll be satisfied with it...

Comment: The output image in red/black is pretty. +1

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit of a cheat (and I guess technically not answering the question), but you could download the fonts from the [DSEG project](https://github.com/keshikan/DSEG) put one of them (in this case I used `DSEG7Classic-Regular.ttf`) the in the same folder as your tex source file and compile the following with `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX`:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85} % Not required for XeLaTeX
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec,xcolor}
\newfontfamily{\dseg}[Path=./]{DSEG7Classic-Regular}
\def\display#1{\setbox0=\hbox{\textcolor{on}{\dseg#1}}%
\hbox to\wd0{\textcolor{off}{\dseg\leaders\hbox{8}\hfill\null}}%
\kern-\wd0\box0}
\colorlet{on}{red}
\colorlet{off}{gray!10}
\begin{document}
\display{0123456789abcdef}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can try this package write by Germain Gondor.
Doc. in French and English
https://sciences-indus-cpge.papanicola.info/Afficheur-7-Segments-avec-PGF-TIKZ